# Why does a primitive root mod n gives a uniform distribution over n?

Tags: number-theory

The result from a primitive root mod `n` seemly has a uniform distribution over `n`, is it true? For instance, 3 is a primitive root mod 7, and the result seems to be randomly distributed over 1 and 6,

[image: From wiki]

I wonder why is it, or should I just take it as a basic fact of our universe?

Comment: Welcome to CSE. What exactly remains unclear after looking at the [definition of a primitive root modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n): _"A number $g$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if every number $a$ coprime to $n$ is congruent to a power of $g$ modulo $n$"_?

Comment: @fgrieu the definition gives no information about the assumption/conclusion on the distribution generated from $g^x$ mod n. I'm curious about whether it preserves uniform distribution and why so.

Comment: @yyforyongyu: I often answer classical exercises with hints, here the definition is an important one. SEJPM went further. Be sure to understand his line of thought: with appropriate $n$, $g$ including $n=7$, $g=3$, the transformation $x\to g^x\bmod n$ is a reversible mapping of the set $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, hence for uniform $x$ on that set the outcome is uniform (further, we can map $0$ to itself for a reversible mapping of the full $\Bbb Z_n$). Beware that _natural phenomenon_ often are Gaussian, that's not the case here.

Comment: @fgrieu thanks for the clarification. I guess I should be careful when choosing words here. When I say **natural phenomenon**, what I meant was, the uniform distribution is created by the nature of the universe, just like the value $π$, thus I will take its existence for granted since it's beyond explanation. I have to say I'm still learning the necessary terminologies here to be able to construct a clear and meaningful question/discussion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

From [the definition of a primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n), as recovered by fgrieu:

> A number $g$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if every number $a$ coprime to $n$ is congruent to a power of $g$ modulo $n$

and following-up from that:

This implies that $f(x)=g^x\bmod n$ is a bijection into $\mathbb Z_n^*$, the set of all integers smaller than and co-prime to $n$ greater than 0, i.e. $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n-1\}$ for a prime $n$. It's a bijection because every element can be reached (surjective) and no element is reached twice (injective) when iterating through all values $x$ just until (exclusive) you hit the first repetition in values. It's also a classic result that applying a bijection to a uniformly distributed variable results in a still uniformly distributed variable, i.e. bijections preserve uniform distribution.